# Are there any optimizations to factorial calculations?

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory

Both the iterative and recursive versions run at linear time complexity.  Are there any optimizations that can be made?

```
// O(n)
function factorial (n) {
  let ret = 1;
  for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    ret = ret * i;
  }
  return ret;
}

// O(n)
function factorialR (n) {
  if( n === 0 || n === 1 ) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorialR(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Possibly of interest](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm)

Comment: In an interview setting, what do you think would be the next step, if interviewer said make it faster, and you don't have access to that link?

Comment: Point being you just know the def. of factorial and how to code and you have to figure it out ...

Comment: store all the solutions in an array and you can do it in constant time

Comment: @j.a. unless the interview is for a position that *heavily* requires maths or otherwise relies on you absolutely positively knowing all of this by heart, I suggest your answer is: "I would research and implement a more efficient behaviour, I just don't know what it is now". Or something to that effect. We don't and probably *shouldn't* know all answers to highly specific problems. There are people who've done the research, so we can refer to their work. Some interviewers do push you to try and perfect something you don't know and...I can just say they are wrong.

Comment: For raw compute, I think these functions are good. Any optimizations would have to do with planned use - if used over and over it may make sense to save computed values as suggested. If the expected limit of n is low, it may make sense to pre-compute and hardcode in some solutions. If they are getting used in permutations/ combinations, you can often shortcut needing the full factorials at all. An interviewer will appreciate looking at the big picture like this.

Comment: @Chris - this is called memoization I believe.  Sounds like what an interviewer would expect as this is the next easiest step.

Comment: @j.a. it could also be a trap. Sure, memoization will help in *specific circumstances*. If you have lots of calls to a memoized factorial function, then only the first would be `O(n)`, the rest will benefit from (at least some) caching. So `factorial(10)` followed by `factorial(8)` will lead to fetching from cache, while `factorial(8)` and then `factorial(10)` will lead to only computing for `10` and `9` in the second case. However, `factorial(10000)` will lead to memory bloat, especially if most values would not be used later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are doing research, the interviewer will likely want to test the way you think.

Showing both the iterative and recursive version with explanation of the Big O should be adequate for starters.

If asked to optimize, qualify with a use case and suggest memoization if applicable.

If asked to optimize with out memoization do the chicken dance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to do it
check this out:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication
http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Might require bit manipulation, not exactly encouraged in high-level languages though